# routes in api not being recognized when moved but in the same scope

Tags: php, laravel, routes

When I move a route from the api routes it dessapear and I foound a not found error. But it's moving in the same route::group

I have tried route:cache, route:clear, route config but nothing work
with this it works:

```
            Route::get('asistencias/all', 'AsistenciaController@all')->name('asistencias.all');
            Route::get('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@show')->name('asistencias.show');
            Route::put('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@update')->name('asistencias.update');
            Route::delete('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@destroy')->name('asistencias.delete');
```

but with this small change doesn't:

```
            Route::get('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@show')->name('asistencias.show');
            Route::put('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@update')->name('asistencias.update');
            Route::delete('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@destroy')->name('asistencias.delete');
            Route::get('asistencias/all', 'AsistenciaController@all')->name('asistencias.all');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example the route with the parameter, `asistencias/{asistencia}` will match a path like `asistencias/all` so that route would get used instead of the one defined as `asistencias/all` if the request was for `asistencias/all`.

```
Route::get('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@show')->name('asistencias.show');
Route::get('asistencias/all', 'AsistenciaController@all')->name('asistencias.all');
```

The first matched route gets used.

Your first example defines the route `asistencia/all` before `asistencia/{asistencia}`.

```
Route::get('asistencias/all', 'AsistenciaController@all')->name('asistencias.all');
Route::get('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@show')->name('asistencias.show');
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is overtaking any get request:

```
Route::get('asistencias/{asistencia}', 'AsistenciaController@show')->name('asistencias.show');
```

Put this line after all the other lines.